# Загрузка изображений на сервер

Tags: php

Возникла проблема с загрузкой изображений на сервер (локальный Openserver)

после того как нажимаю сабмит происходит вот что

Array ( [userfile] => Array ( [name] => banner_970kh80-04.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => E:\OpenServer\userdata\temp\php56B4.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 40162 ) )

вот сам скрипт

```
  <?php 
   $uploaddir = 'images/';
   $apend=date('YmdHis').rand(100,1000).'.jpg'; 
   $uploadfile = "$uploaddir$apend"; 
   if(($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'image/gif' ||
     $_FILES['userfile'] ['type'] == 'image/jpeg' || 
      $_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'image/png')||
     $_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'image/jpeg' &&
   ($_FILES['userfile']['size'] != 0 and $_FILES['userfile']['size']<=512000)) 
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
  { 
     echo "Файл загружен. Путь к файлу: <p>http:/yoursite.ru/".$uploadfile." </p>"; 
  } else {
 echo "Загружаемое изображение превышает допустимые нормы (ширина не более - 500; высота не более 1500)"; 
 unlink($uploadfile); 
 // удаление файла 
 } 
 } else {
   echo "Файл не загружен, вернитеcь и попробуйте еще раз";
 } 
  } else { 
 echo "Размер файла не должен превышать 512Кб";
 } 
 ?>
```

Comment: Изображения не загружаются в папку

Comment: В корне сайта лежит папка images, в которую по идее должно прийти изображение, но после нажатия отправить мне выдает массив Array ( [userfile] => Array ( [name] => banner_970kh80-04.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => E:\OpenServer\userdata\temp\php56B4.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 40162 ) ) и все, я пробовал разные скрипты, результат один и тот же

Comment: может быть нету права на запись - chmod('images/',0777) добавьте в начало файла

Comment: не помогло((( дело в том что и не выводит сообщение об ошибке, скрипт принимает изображение, но какого-то лешего выдает мне массив и не копирует файл в папку

Comment: Это вообще точно тот скрипт? я, например, не вижу тут никакого вывода. Добавьте в начале скрипта какое-нибудь echo "test"; чтобы убедиться что это нужный скрипт. Потом во все if добавьте  echo "такое действие"; чтобы понять как рабтает ваш скрипт

Comment: а можно весь код? а то слишком много else для двух if

Comment: @G.Denis, да там и после первого `if` нет открывающей фигурной скобки, несмотря на то, что перед `else` закрывающая есть.

Comment: я бы еще обратил внимание на скобку в проверке `mime-type` не в том месте, и на `and` при проверке размера файла

Comment: да и удаление временных файлов (`unlink($uploadFile)`) это не ваша задача, этим сервер занимается, собственно он и удалить этот файл не даст. Для работы с ними предназначены всего две функции.

Comment: да и переименовыввать файла всегда в jpeg (`$append='.jpg'`) для любого mime-type - не лучший ход.

Comment: и часть `else` с ошибкой про длину-ширину картинки вообще не понятно к чему привязана. и 512000 байт это несколько меньше чем 512Кбайт

Comment: Всем  спасибо, обратил внимание на ошибки, все работает теперь)))